# How do I make chroot run a command?

Tags: linux, bash, chroot, lfs

I have a problem with compiling an [LFS](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable) system on Linux Mint 20 with Cinnamon. My problem is that when I get to the (third?) pass of Glibc, `chroot` doesn't let me run any commands, telling me that they aren't directories. The exact output of chroot is this:

```
root@LAPTOP:~# chroot "$LFS" /usr/bin/env -i HOME=/root TERM="$TERM" PS1='(lfs chroot) \u:\w\$ ' \
                                             PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin \
                                             /bin/bash --login +h
chroot: failed to run command '/usr/bin/env': Not a directory
```

I don't know what the issue is here. Could someone please give me a pointer?

P.S. If there is a better site to put this on, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, I found out what was going on.

Early on when I first made the filesystem, I made /lib a symlink to /usr/lib.
Then when I ran these commands:

```
case $(uname -m) in
  i?86)   ln -sfnv $PWD/elf/ld-linux.so.2        /lib ;;
  x86_64) ln -sfnv $PWD/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib ;;
esac
```

It changed the target of the link to `$PWD/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, so the file that wasn't a directory was /lib.